# Using Qt3D for a huge topography model?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, qt3d

My scene currently consists of a huge topography model (Mill. Verticies). Now the scene becomes more complex and contains many smaller 3D objects. Does it make sense to switch from a QFrambufferObject (with C ++ / OpenGL) to Qt3D?

1. What about the speed?
2. Which file format (Wavefront OBJ, Stanford Triangle Format PLY, STL (STereoLithography)) is suitable? I am currently loading the data from the .hgt format into a vector array and then into the QFrambufferObject.
3. With Qt3D, is it possible to load only the tiles in the graphics card that are currently visible in the viewport or to delete them as soon as they leave the viewport when the camera angles change?

Answer (score 2):

That's difficult to say. I assume by

> Does it make sense to switch

you mean will it be fast enough. Regarding your two points:

1. Qt3D uses [assimp](https://www.assimp.org/) internally to load models, so if that library is able to load hgt files, so should be Qt3D.
2. What do you mean by reload? Do they change dynamically in the model? Or do you mean re-render? There's [`QFrustumCullung`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qfrustumculling.html) but that seems to render the whole entity still. Do you know whether your object consists of multiple parts? Because when Qt3D loads models (i.e. whole scenes) from files I think it persists its structure. If your model is split into multiple standalone components it could be that `QFrustumCulling` improves rendering speed because they don't get drawn when they are not viewed.

I personally feel like Qt3D is slower compared to a hand-crafted renderer in OpenGL. But it constantly improves so if it doesn't take long to try it out maybe it's worth a shot. Also, the flexibility of Qt3D might make up for the slower rendering speed.

Comment: I just updated my question to makes it more clear. QFrustumCullung sound interesting.